# Execute menu commands in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a custom plugin that was made for powerpoint and has a functionality to export the current slide as HTML5. It doesn't support exporting the entire PPT so basically I would have to go slide by slide and export.

My question is, can I write something in VB that can execute a menu command, finish, next slide, execute menu command etc?

I don't even know if VB would be the correct language to use. I've never written anything in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA might be simpler since it's built into PowerPoint.

If you know the name of the command bar and the control on the command bar that you want to launch:

```
Sub LaunchTheCommand()
    Dim oCmdbar As CommandBar
    Set oCmdbar = Application.CommandBars("CommandBarName")
    oCmdbar.Controls("ControlName").Execute
End Sub
```

View | Toolbars will show you the names of your toolbars.

This could help you work out the right name for the individual controls:

```
Sub ShowTheControlNames()
    Dim oCmdbar As CommandBar
    Dim oCtl As CommandBarControl
    ' for example, let's look at the Standard toolbar:
    Set oCmdbar = Application.CommandBars("Standard")
    For Each oCtl In oCmdbar.Controls
        Debug.Print oCtl.Caption
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that your code won't work on non-English versions of PowerPoint ... the menu names are different.

Comment: thanks for you reply. This is a good starting point I believe. What program do I use for this? MS Visual Basic? Once I am in that program, how do I execute the command? Sorry for my ignorance lol

Comment: As I mentioned, you can use VBA ... it's built into PowerPoint. I maintain a PowerPoint FAQ site that has more info on using VBA in PowerPoint. Have a look here for starters:  How do I use VBA code in PowerPoint
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00033_How_do_I_use_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint.htm